# How to place pauses in a sentence when speaking?

Tags: speech

I would like to know how to place pauses in a sentence when speaking (besides pauses on comma and semicolon) to deliver a better message to audiences. I researched this for a while but I don't find any formal documents on this subject on the internet.

Here is an example I found:

> Now that you have reduced the word count of your presentation // you
>   need to prepare your message in shorter, // simpler // chunks.  To do
>   this well // you need to consider where to place stress in words and
>   in sentences, // where to pause naturally in your speech // and where
>   // to pause for effect.

Comment: Why my question is closed? It's all about:
- Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
- Spelling and punctuation

Comment: Feel free to bring this up in [meta] if you need a more detailed explanation that what is provided in the [faq].